# Gnome keyring stays unlocked permanently

Tags: gnome-keyring

It used to be that my gnome keyring would go back to being locked after I rebooted and I'd have to enter the passphrase to unlock again, but now it stays unlocked unless I manually lock it with [seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse/).  How do I restore the old behavior where the keyring relocks on reboot?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that gnome keyring stored the passphrase for my default keyring in a special keyring named "Login", and unlocked that keyring with my login password.  The [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) config files for console login and [SDDM](https://github.com/sddm/sddm) login use the [gnome keyring PAM module](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam).  It can be disabled by commenting out the lines containing `pam_gnome_keyring.so` from all files containing that string in the directory `/etc/pam.d`; this should make it so that you have to manually enter the passphrase to unlock your keyring.